# Show webcam stream in CEF 1 / appjs?

Tags: webcam, chromium-embedded, appjs

I'm running appjs and I'm thinking of showing live content from the local webcam in the html and would like some hints on how to do this.

/Kristofer

Answer (score 2):

Appjs is built on top of CEF so I think I am correct in saying that at the moment this functionality is not available out of the box. However the next version of AppJS will use content api which means that media and video should be available.

For now I would suggest that you develop your application in HTML5 using chrome and then run it inside AppJS later on when it catches up and provides these functions out of the box.

Comment: Ok, CEF 3 seems to have support for it but appjs uses CEF 1 for now.